# @After annotation doesn't work with parameters in Play! Framework with Scala module

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm encountering a problem with interceptors in Play! Framework (1.2.3) with Scala module (0.9.1).

I have a following code which should run whenSuccess method after invocation of 'index' method, but it doesn't happen.

```
@After(only=Array("index")) def whenSuccess = {println("I'm a hero")  }

def index={
     Html('Hello world')
 }

 def returnXML = {
     Xml("<helloinfo>Hello world in XML</helloinfo>")
 }
 ...
```

whenSuccess is not invoked when i specify 'only' parameter. without any param it works, but i want to restrict it to happen only when 'index' method fired.

May be I'm doing something wrong?

Many thanks for advises!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@After doesn't seem to work at all (@Before works, though). I found this ticket with an open pull-request:
https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/74274/tickets/24-after-controller-interceptor-doesnt-work Milestone is set to 0.9.2.